# PHP fetch_array object error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve data from my mysql database using object `mysqli -> fetch_array()` method. But I can't becausse I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /usr/home/.../web/modelos/usuario-model.php on line 51

Here is my code:

```
function datoscorrectos($nombre,$csenya)
{
    $dtcorrectos = false;
    //$cn = $this -> establecer_conexion();
    $cn = new mysqli(SERVIDOR_BBDD,USUARIO_BBDD,CONTRASENA_BBDD,NOMBRE_BBDD);

    $cp = "select nombre, contrasenya from usuarios where usuario = " . $nombre;
    $cbd = $cn -> query($cp);
    echo "nombre " . $nombre;

    while($cbd->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {   
        echo $fp["nombre"];
        if($nombre === $fp["nombre"]) 
         {
            if($csenya === $fp["contrasenya"]) 
             {
                $dtcorrectos = true;
                break;
             }  
         }
    }

    return $dtcorrectos;
}
```

How can I retrieve data?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the error. `$cbd` is not an object. null?

Comment: How/where does `$fp` come into the picture?

Comment: Sounds to me like your query failed.  Add `mysqli_error($cn);` to your query, i.e: `if ($cn->error) {
    try {    
        throw new Exception("MySQL error $cn->error <br> Query:<br> $query", $cn->errno);    
    } catch(Exception $e ) {
        echo "Error No: ".$e->getCode(). " - ". $e->getMessage() . "<br >";
        echo nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}` plus this won't hurt: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that custom strings has to be wrapped between single quotes in your SQL query:

```
"select nombre, contrasenya from usuarios where usuario = '$nombre'";
                                                          ^       ^
```

Comment: this will produce the opportunity for an [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) unless `$nombre` is properly escaped (eg. using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)). (though I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @Lee Yes, that's correct, but not the question, I think downvoting because of that is a bit excessive.

Comment: @wumm - No you may not, because I did not downvote your answer. But I have upvoted it, hope that makes you feel better!

Comment: @raidenace Ah, sorry for bothering you, mixed up two questions in different tabs

Comment: @wumm As I noted: I did not downvote your answer.  I just put the comment there to warn those that might copy/paste without fully understanding the implications.  Do not make assumptions about the source of downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is fixed. It is the query. The table was wrong. I change it and now it works.

Comment: @axmug *"Thanks for answering. The problem is fixed. It is the query. The table was wrong. I change it and now it works."* - If the table was wrong, then why did you accept this answer as being correct? An answer should only be accepted if it was in fact the actual issue. Which, from what I can tell by your comment, isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your SQL statements are correct and also remove the spaces from 
`$cn -> query($cp);` - though not incorrect, its not a good programming practice.

Basically your  `$cbd` object is not getting created.

Comment: Ever heard of OO? That's a mysqli method: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php